# insert multiple datetime values in a single column in one row in mysql using java

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, datepicker

I need to insert multiple data time values in single column in a row,
How to achieve this?

I searched google for this, I seen insert multiple rows in a single query solutions, but I need to insert multiple values in a single column and row.

i tried INSERT INTO table_name (date_column) VALUES ('20-10-2011'), ('20-10-2011'), ('21-10-2011'), ('22-10-2011'), ('23-10-2011'), ('24-10-2011');

but it will insert dates in multiple rows, i want them to be inserted in single column in a row.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

**Update :**

I tried like Below

Query is :

```
    SELECT  
  *
FROM (                                   
  SELECT                                 
    employeeId,
    availabilityDate, 
    IF(timeOff=0,1,0) AS '0', 
    IF(timeOff=1,1,0) AS '1', 
    IF(timeOff=2,1,0) AS '2',
    IF(timeOff=3,1,0) AS '3',
    IF(timeOff=4,1,0) AS '4',
    IF(timeOff=5,1,0) AS '5',
    IF(timeOff=6,1,0) AS '6',
    IF(timeOff=7,1,0) AS '7',
    IF(timeOff=8,1,0) AS '8',
    IF(timeOff=9,1,0) AS '9',
    IF(timeOff=10,1,0) AS '10',
    IF(timeOff=11,1,0) AS '11'    
  FROM sample 
) AS test;
```

Comment: What do you mean with "in one column in a one row" inserting them in diferents rows of the samee column, diferent columns of the same row or all of them in a single cell (same column and row)?

Comment: I think the normal database advice would be "_don't_ try and insert multiple date/time values in one column in one row"

Comment: show your expected result

Comment: What is the data type of the `date_column` column ?

Comment: FYI : here date_coumn is varchar data type.

Comment: In that case, you can use this insert statement: `INSERT INTO table_name(date_column) VALUES('20-10-2011, 20-10-2011, 21-10-2011, 22-10-2011, 23-10-2011, 24-10-2011')`.

Comment: What @Titus said does the trick, but as @khelwood said above, you should not do that, first because it is not a good database design, second because it relies on the size of the `varchar` type, which may (or may not) be limited (by you or by the system). Plus, if you have to work on that field, you have a very big string to process instead of a set of dates, which are easier to manage.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot insert multiple date values in a DateTime column of any database.
Alternatively, you can have a column with varchar(XXX) or clob/blob datatype and insert multiple datetime values into it (may be separated with a delimiter, which makes easy to retrieve each value separately).
Hope this helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the Java tag as this question has nothing to do with Java.

The question comes down to the fact that you have misunderstood something. One field in SQL contains one value. You can  it appear to contain multiple values by changing the datatype and have your program perform the logic.

Guessing from your limited example I would suspect that you need to rethink your data structure. Multiple dates sound like dates of some kind of event and that something you put in relation table.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this with a query? If so I´m trying to achieve the same thing, to merge multiple years as one.

**As an example (inserts all the same dates in a row) you can try;**

```
INSERT INTO tableX( fx, fx, fx, singledate)
SELECT...
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(thedates '%d-%m-%Y'))),
etc...
```

Plus, your row must be in text format.